# How to specify a window size by rows instead of DURATION in DolphinDB?

Tags: window-functions, dolphindb

Does the parameter window of `wj` function only support duration type? How should I approach it if I want to select by rows?

M data are all based on trading days. Data in a duration type window will be NULL if it's weekends or holidays. I'm now using `moving` for backward sliding windows. Any functions for forward sliding windows, like `moving(fun, X, -n)`?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `wj` function only supports duration type. There are two types of high-order functions: `window` and `twindow` that were introduced for forward sliding window calculations.